# How to Set value for password filed using Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

This My Edit user form in Zend Frame work

```
  $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    $this->setName('user');
    $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
    $id->addFilter('Int');
    $fname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('fname');
    $fname->setLabel('Full Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
    $email->setLabel('Email Address')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $add = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('add');
    $add->setLabel('Address')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $pass = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('pass');
    $pass->setLabel('Password')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

    $city = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('city');
    $city->setLabel('city')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $img = new Zend_Form_Element_File('img');
    $img->setLabel('Profile picture')
            ->setRequired(true);


    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

    // add element in form
    $this->addElements(array($id, $fname, $email, $add, $pass, $city, $img, $submit));
```

And I am Set the value for form elemets using following code in controller

```
  $form = new Application_Form_User();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Save');
    $this->view->form = $form;

   $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
        if ($id > 0) {
            $user = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
            $info = $user->getUser($id);
            //$form->populate($info);
            $form->setDefaults($info);
```

I am used $form->setDefaults($info); methode to set vlaue for form field. This method set value sucessfully for only Text input type but This method can not set value which has input type is password. so, what would i do for set vlaue for to input type is password?
This is my output screen edit.php

[image: edit.php]

Answer (score 0):

Zend does not allow password field to be auto-filled. Html type="password" also prevents the browsers to supports autocomplete.  You will have to enter the password manually each time the page is refreshed.

However to disable autocomplete on a field use.

```
$foo = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('foo', array( 
        'autocomplete' => 'off', 
    )); 

    // or... 
    $form->addElement('text', 'foo', array( 
        'autocomplete' => 'off', 
    )); 

    // or... 
    $element->autocomplete = 'off';
```

Comment: I try this code in edit user form and it works.                $pass->renderPassword = true;
$pass->setValue("amt");

Comment: If you are sure that this works, you must add an answer to your own question. Let others share this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I came across it whilst looking for the same answer so I thought I'd post my findings.

There is a `setRenderPassword(true)` property for password fields in Zend_Form.

```
$pass = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('pass');
$pass->setLabel('Password')
     ->setRequired(true)
     ->addFilter('StripTags')
     ->addFilter('StringTrim')
     ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
     ->setRenderPassword(true);
```